# Receive an array of strings from a function and find out it's length

Tags: c, arrays, string

I have this code:

```
char** SplitToWords(char* str);

int main()
{
    char** wordarr;
    char str[] = "This is a sentence";
    wordarr = SplitToWords(str);

    return 0;
}
```

After the main comes the function implementation.

1. I am not sure the following does what I want it to do (i.e. receive an array of strings from a function):

   ```
   wordarr = SplitToWords(str);
   ```

   I somehow managed to convince the compiler that it's ok, but I assume it just does something else.
2. If it does, how do I find out the length of the array (the number of strings in it).

Thanks

Comment: (2) Place `NULL` after the pointer of the last word.

Comment: How do you expect us to know when you don't post the code for `SplitToWords` ?

Comment: Let me clarify- I asked whether an array of strings is assigned to wordarr assuming the function returns charr**. I did not ask if the function does what it supposed to do. Thanks

Comment: In C, you never return an array. You return a *pointer* to an array. And yes, you can do what you describe with a function with return value `char **`.

Comment: If your function returns a pointer there's no way to know if it points to a single element or an array of unknown length. In your case, since you have a pointer to `char*` use BLUEPIXY's suggestion and add a `NULL` pointer to the end of the array as a sentinel that you can search for.

Comment: 1. Without seeing the code, it's impossible to tell. If you need to "convince the compiler" of anything, you need to explain what the compiler told you. and 2. You can add an extra element to the array and set it to `NULL`, then use a function to compute the length, similar to how you might implement `strlen` to look for the terminating `'\0'` byte. You could also just use the array elements directly without the need to compute the length if you don't need to index the array. Alternatively, use an "out parameter" to return the array length (e.g. `char **words = SplitToWords(str, &wcount);`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll try to quickly visit all aspects you might not yet fully understand:

1. A **string** in C is described as a contiguous sequence of `char`s, ending with a `char` of value `0` (as a literal: `'\0'`). It is not a *first class object*, therefore hasn't its own *type*. So what you use to hold a *string* is an array of `char`. Therefore, taking your question by the word, "*receive an array of strings from a function*" is not possible.
2. An **array** is a contiguous sequence of objects of the same type. In C, the identifier of an array doesn't have a value itself; when it's evaluated, it decays as a *pointer* to the array's first element instead. This is especially important when passing arrays to functions or returning them from functions -- you can't actually pass the array, you always pass a pointer

   e.g. you could write:

   ```
   char x[] = "foo"; // initialize a char array from a string literal
   char *xp = x;     // here, x evaluates as a pointer to the first element of the array
   ```

   You already use pointer types for your function's argument and return value, I just think it's quite important to understand what happens entirely.
3. You write `char** SplitToWords(char* str);` and ask whether this returns an "array of strings" -- well, **sort of**, as you should understand after reading 1. and 2. -- What it does is returning a pointer to `char *`. This pointer **could** be a pointer to the first element of an array. So in this case, it would return a pointer to an array of `char *` pointers. Each of these pointers could itself be a pointer to an array of `chars`, therefore point to a **string**. But what's **very** important is to understand you never return an array, you always return a pointer to it. It's so important because:
4. You **might** get the idea to do something like this:

   ```
   char** SplitToWords(char* str)
   {
       char *words[16];
       // code to fill `words` with pointers to the actual words
       return words; // WRONG!
   }
   ```

   Here, because you're not returning the **array** `words` but a pointer to it (see point 2), you return a pointer to an object that *no longer exists*. `words` is in the scope of your function and has automatic storage duration, that means it only lives as long as the execution is inside of the function. One solution would be to declare `words` with the `static` storage class specifier. This way, it lives for the entire execution time of the program. But be aware that this also means there's *only a single instance ever*, it's always the same object. This will be a major headache for threaded programs, for example. The other way around is to *dynamically allocate* `words` using `malloc()`. But then, the caller of the function must `free()` it later.

---

As for your second question, how to let the caller know the number of words -- it's in the comments already, but just for completeness, a typical approach to solve this is to append *another* entry that is a `NULL` pointer. So the caller can iterate over the pointers until it finds `NULL`.

---

Regarding your comment, of course you can create the array outside the function and pass a pointer to the function, so the function only fills it. This is a common idiom in C (e.g. think about `fgets()`, which takes a pointer to the `char` array that's filled with a string by the function).

Functions working this way will need an additional `size_t` parameter, so they know the size of the array they should fill through the pointer, otherwise you'd have the risk of buffer overflows (this is why [`gets()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/gets.3.html) was finally *removed* from the C standard). If you decide that the caller provides the storage, your function should have this prototype:

```
// returns the number of words found, up to `nwords`
size_t SplitToTwords(char **words, size_t nwords, char *str);
```

It should be called e.g. like this:

```
char *words[16];
size_t nwords = SplitToWords(words, 16, "the quick brown fox"); // returns 4
```

Remember that the strings holding the words themselves need storage as well. You can either manipulate the bytes in `str` to insert a `'\0'` after each word, overwriting the first whitespace character (this is what `strtok()` does) or you can copy the words to new strings, but then you would have to `malloc()` each of them again and the caller has to `free()` them later.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer! I realize now that I need to better understand how to send string pointers and especially pointers to string arrays. I'll try o to change my function so it actually receives the char** and does what I want it to go.

Comment: @Hana probably a good idea, see my edit for some remarks on it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could solve it by using a function with return value `char **`. However, there's no way to find out how many words there are afterwards.

You can solve this by allocating one more element for the return pointer and set it to NULL. Then you can get the number of words with this code:

```
wordarr = SplitToWords(str);
char **ptr=wordarr;
int noWords=0;
while(!*(ptr+noWords))
    noWords++;
```

But if you want to return multiple data in C, you either need to define a return `struct` or using return arguments. In this case, it could look like this for the first option:

```
typedef struct wordList {
    char **wordarr;
    int noWords;
}

wordList SplitToWords(char* str);
```

And the second:

```
char** SplitToWords(char* str, int *noWords);
```

or

```
void SplitToWords(char* str, char*** wordarr, int *noWords);
```

Note that there's three `*`. That's because we want it to be a pointer to `char **`

Comment: Don't be a [Three Star Programmer](http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>  

#define MAXSTRINGS  5000


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char *stringTable[MAXSTRINGS];

    char sentence[] = "This is a sentence";

    char *token = NULL;

    int i = 0;

    while ((token = strtok(token == NULL ? sentence : NULL, " ")) != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n\r", token);
        stringTable[i] = (char *)malloc(strlen(token) + 1);  //have no "plain" C compiler - VS C++ used so cast needed :)
        strcpy(stringTable[i++], token);
    }
    stringTable[i] = NULL; // if you need to iterate through later
    printf("%d tokens found\n\r", i);

    for (int y = 0; y < i; y++)
        free(stringTable[y]);
}
```